# Going to next page when web scraping with Jsoup

Tags: java, android-studio, web-scraping, jsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape this https://www.actksa.com/ar/training-courses/training-in/Jeddah with Jsoup the code I wrote only takes the Subjects on the first page.

```
try {
                String url = "https://www.actksa.com/ar/training-courses/training-in/Jeddah";

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                Elements data = doc.select("tr");
                int size = data.size();
                Log.d("doc", "doc: "+doc);
                Log.d("data", "data: "+data);
                Log.d("size", ""+size);
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                    String title = data.select("td.wp-60")
                            .eq(i)
                            .text();

                    String detailUrl = data.select("td.wp-60")
                            .select("a")
                            .eq(i)
                            .attr("href");
                    parseItems.add(new ParseItem(title, detailUrl));
                    Log.d("items"," . title: " + title);
```

How can I continue scraping subjects from the next pages?
I noticed that I may be able to use pagination but I am not sure how. and second, the link changes slightly when going to the next page so I could maybe use that. What's the code to go to the next pages and continue scraping titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the pagination for that site is controlled by the `?page=<int>` query parameter.
Simply wrap your existing code in a `for` loop that will control the current page.

```
int numPages = 5; // the number of pages to scrape
for (int i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
    String url = "https://www.actksa.com/ar/training-courses/training-in/Jeddah?page=" + i;

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    Elements data = doc.select("tr");
    int size = data.size();
    Log.d("doc", "doc: "+doc);
    Log.d("data", "data: "+data);
    Log.d("size", ""+size);
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
         String title = data.select("td.wp-60")
                .eq(j)
                .text();
         String detailUrl = data.select("td.wp-60")
                .select("a")
                .eq(j)
                .attr("href");
        parseItems.add(new ParseItem(title, detailUrl));
        Log.d("items"," . title: " + title);
    }
}
```

If you want to get all the pages without hardcoding the numbers, you put the incrementing in a while loop that will break when the table on the page has no contents. For example `https://www.actksa.com/ar/training-courses/training-in/jeddah?page=6` is not a valid page, and just shows a page with an empty table.